# Let object follow two paths?

Tags: animation, constraints, path

I want to add two follow path constraints to a single object.

That means I want my object to follow path A, then do something else and then the object should follow path B, which begins at the end of path A.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Animate the influence property of both constraints over time

Comment: I cannot leave a comment at other Posts so I add one here.

When I try to insert keyframe at Evaluation Time I get an error : F-Curve with path 'eval_time[0]' cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers.